# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly - Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, windows-authentication

I have an application in .net core. the application was running fine, but the error started coming after I installed
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate --version 6.0.14
Once I installed this package and put this line of code in startup.cs file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

I started getting this error:

**

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=6.0.0.1, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file
> specified.'

**

I installed this package when I saw the above error:

dotnet add package System.DirectoryServices --version 7.0.0

I am still getting this error. The error is coming in program.cs file. below is the screen shot of the error:
[image]

why the application is looking for 6.0.0.1 version when I have 7.0.0 version installed. Below is packages installed on my application?

I also installed

```
<PackageReference Include="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" Version="7.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes, it seems you are using the .net core 3.1 or early version.

But you install the .net 6.0 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate package, I suggest you could select the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate package version to match your application version and then it will work well.

[image]